# Computationally 'lightweight' smoothing in realtime

Tags: smoothing

I have a pitch tracker that can be quite unsmooth in its output (in Hz). A Savitzky-Golay filter has been good at smoothing but it looks like it adds a lot of multiplies on top of the already intensive `O(N^2)` multiplies from the autocorrelator doing the pitch tracking. Should I just do linearly interpolate between the previous point, or the point before that? What else can I look into? Will a single lowpass biquad deal with it?

Comment: i wouldn't LPF.  not without doing something like a median filter to kick out bad pitch points.

Comment: a median filter just takes the median of some previous N inputs and uses that as the output?

Comment: yes, that's what a median filter does.  the problem with pitch detection is that you have to figure out when you are in between notes and when you are, my suggestion is that you somehow hold, in the output, the last good pitch value.  so when the note ends, your *unfiltered* pitch is gonna start going wild, you want to detect when that happens, and then hold the last "good" pitch until the next good note is detected.